# Scrapy issue spider python

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm working on a crawling project with scrapy. I'm trying to take laws from the website legifrance.gouv.fr.

I'm working on the code called "code général des impôts". The idea of my script is to parse the summary of the page https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCode.do;jsessionid=F17704445BF9676D75495A907656E918.tpdila14v_3?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006069577&dateTexte=20160308
and then I'm going on each page links in the summary. Then I'm trying to get back each article with his name and his path. After this I will put every article in database to be able to do requests.

My issue is that my script is working but I have some... "bug". I managed to have the path, the name of the article but sometimes I don't get back the article. Moreover, if there are more than one article on the page I don't get back all names with the article associated.

Finding a solution would be awesome ! I'm still trying to find it by myself.

Thank you

This is my script:

```
import scrapy

from tutorial.items import GouvItem

class GouvSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "gouv"

    allowed_domains = ["legifrance.gouv.fr"]

    start_urls = [

        "http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCode.do?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006069577&dateTexte=20160216"

       ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath(".//span[@class='codeLienArt']/a/@href"):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_article)


    def parse_article(self, response):
        for art in response.xpath(".//div[@class='data']"):
            item = GouvItem()
            item['title1'] = art.xpath("ul/li/a/text()").extract()

            if len(art.xpath("ul/li/ul/li/a/text()").extract()) > 0:
                item['title2'] = art.xpath("ul/li/ul/li/a/text()").extract()

            if len(art.xpath("ul/li/ul/li/ul/li/a/text()").extract()) > 0:
                item['title3'] = art.xpath("ul/li/ul/li/ul/li/a/text()").extract()

            if len(art.xpath("ul/li/ul/li/ul/li/ul/li/a/text()").extract()) > 0:
                item['title4'] = art.xpath("ul/li/ul/li/ul/li/ul/li/a/text()").extract()

            if len(art.xpath("ul/li/ul/li/ul/li/ul/li/ul/li/a/text()").extract()) > 0:
                item['title5'] = art.xpath("ul/li/ul/li/ul/li/ul/li/ul/li/a/text()").extract()

            if len(art.xpath("ul/li/ul/li/ul/li/ul/li/ul/li/ul/li/a/text()").extract()) > 0:
                item['title6'] = art.xpath("ul/li/ul/li/ul/li/ul/li/ul/li/ul/li/a/text()").extract()

            item['title7'] = art.xpath(".//div[@class='titreSection']/text()").extract()

            yield item

        for titreart in response.xpath(".//div[@class='article']"):
            item = GouvItem()
            item['title_art'] = titreart.xpath(".//text()").extract()
            yield item
```

After using a filter I have this result :

[{"title1": ["Livre premier : Assiette et liquidation de l'impôt"], "title2": ["Première Partie : Impôts d'\u00c9tat"], "title3": ["Titre premier : Impôts directs et taxes assimilées"], "title4": ["Chapitre premier : Impôt sur le revenu"], "title5": ["Section I : Dispositions générales"], "title7": ["0I : Définition du revenu net global"]},
{"article": [ "Article 1 A ", "Créé par ", "Loi 2005-1719 2005-12-30 art. 74 I Finances pour 2006 JORF 31 décembre 2005", "Il est établi un impôt annuel unique sur le revenu des personnes physiques désigné sous le nom d'impôt sur le revenu. Cet impôt frappe le revenu net global du contribuable déterminé conformément aux dispositions des ", "articles 156 à 168", ". ", "Ce revenu net global est constitué par le total des revenus nets des catégories suivantes :", "-Revenus fonciers ;", "-Bénéfices industriels et commerciaux ;", "-Rémunérations, d'une part, des gérants majoritaires des sociétés à responsabilité limitée n'ayant pas opté pour le régime fiscal des sociétés de personnes dans les conditions prévues au IV de l'article 3 du décret n° 55-594 du 20 mai 1955 modifié et des gérants des sociétés en commandite par actions et, d'autre part, des associés en nom des sociétés de personnes et des membres des sociétés en participation lorsque ces sociétés ont opté pour le régime fiscal des sociétés de capitaux ;", "-Bénéfices de l'exploitation agricole ;", "-Traitements, salaires, indemnités, émoluments, pensions et rentes viagères ;", "-Bénéfices des professions non commerciales et revenus y assimilés ;", "-Revenus de capitaux mobiliers ;", "-Plus-values de cession à titre onéreux de biens ou de droits de toute nature, déterminés conformément aux dispositions des ", "articles 14 à 155", ", total dont sont retranchées les charges énumérées à l'article 156.", ]},
{"title1": ["Livre II : Recouvrement de l'impôt"], "title2": ["Chapitre V : Dégrèvements et restitutions d'impôts"], "title7": ["Section IV : Dispositions communes"]},
{"article": [ "Article 1965 L ", "Modifié par ", "Ordonnance n°2000-916 du 19 septembre 2000 - art. 7 (V) JORF 22 septembre 2000 en vigueur le 1er janvier 2002", "   Les dégrèvements ou restitutions de toutes impositions ou créances fiscales d'un montant inférieur à 8 € ne sont pas effectués.", "   Ce montant s'apprécie par cote, exercice ou affaire.", ]},
{"title1": ["Livre II : Recouvrement de l'impôt"], "title2": ["Chapitre V : Dégrèvements et restitutions d'impôts"], "title3": ["Section II : Juridiction contentieuse"], "title7": ["9 : Dispositions particulières aux contributions indirectes"]},
{"article": [ "Article 1965 FA ", "Modifié par ", "Loi n°86-1318 du 30 décembre 1986 - art. 24 JORF 31 décembre 1986", "   Lorsqu'une personne a indûment acquitté des droits indirects régis par le présent code, elle peut en obtenir le remboursement, à moins que les droits n'aient été répercutés sur l'acheteur.", ]},
{"title1": ["Livre II : Recouvrement de l'impôt"], "title2": ["Chapitre V : Dégrèvements et restitutions d'impôts"], "title3": ["Section II : Juridiction contentieuse"], "title7": ["8 : Dispositions particulières aux droits d'enregistrement, à la taxe de publicité foncière, à la contribution de sécurité immobilière, aux droits de timbre et à la taxe spéciale sur les conventions d'assurances"]},

Comment: Hardcoding the li's like that is not going to work, what if there are more or less than you are searching for? Add a sample of what you expect as output

Comment: Why would you yield title_art and article? isn't it enough to put it on the item?

Comment: I've checked every ul/li and counted them... =D I would like to have :
title, sub_title1, sub_title2, sub_title3, (enough to have the entire path) , title of article and then the article.

I yield title_art and article to get back article and his title on a page which we can find more than 1 article.

I've find a nice solution in not including the second for loop in the first one. But I'm still hardcoding the li's so do you think I can find a better solution ? I've updated my post. Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 0):

You can find both the title1s on that page using the xpath `('//span[@class="TM1Code"]')`, similarly the title2s can be found with `('//span[@class="TM2Code"]')`. These xpaths should be more reliable than the string of ul/li's that you' are currently using. The TMnCodes go all the way down to TM8Code reflecting the heirarchy of the document.

I suggest you create a loop iterating over the TM1Code xpath to get the info you want for each article.